# English Sentences to Linear Logic

Tags: logic, logic-translation, linear-logic

I need to convert the following sentences to Linear Logic formulas-:

1) Bob can spend $1 to purchase a bottle of water or a bag of chips (Bob's
choice). (D means Bob has a dollar; W means Bob has a bottle of water;
C means Bob has a bag of chips.)

2) You can exchange a ten-dollar bill for two five-dollar bills. (T means you
have a ten dollar bill and F means you have one five dollar bill.)

3) If Irene has a water bottle, she can refill it with water as many times as
she wants. (B means Irene has a water bottle; W means Irene has water.)

4) If you give a man a fish, he'll eat for a day (once). If you teach a man
to fish, he'll eat for the rest of his life (as many times as he wants). (F
means you have a fish, E means the man eats, T means you have time to
teach the man to fish.)

5) If you flip a coin it will come up heads or tails (you have no control over
which). (F represents the action of flipping the coin, H means it comes
up heads, T means it comes up tails.)

6) If you have a headache, taking ibuprofen will cure your pain. (H means
you have a headache, I means you have ibuprofen.)

Here are the answers I have till now, could you please confirm these and help me with the ones not completed?

1) D ⊸ W & C

2) T ⊸ F ⊗ F

3) B ⊸ !W

4) No clue

5) F ⊸ H ⊕ T

6) No clue

Answer (score 2):

Your answers for 1), 2), 3) and 5) are correct.

The answer for 4) is: 
\begin{align}
(F ⊸E) \otimes (T ⊸\,\, !E)
\end{align}
Indeed, sentence 4) is the conjunction ($\otimes$) of two linear implications ($⊸$).

The answer for 6) is:
\begin{align}
(H \otimes I) ⊸ H^\perp
\end{align}
Indeed, sentence 6) is a linear implication ($⊸$) where the antecedent is a conjunction ($\otimes$). I interpret "curing your pain" as ''you don't have a headache".